# I need to show text 5 seconds into a video and hide when video is at 10 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a video playing on the site and need text to show at 5 seconds and then hide it after 10 seconds

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('video').on('timeupdate', function() {
    var playTime = Math.round($(this).get(0).currentTime);
    if (playTime == 5) {
      $('txt1').show();
    }
    if (playTime == 10) {
      $('txt1').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: `$('video')[0].on('timeupdate', function() { ... });`  try this....

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use js as well and it might be easier.

```js
// Get the video element with id="myVideo"
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

// Assign an ontimeupdate event to the video element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  // Display the current position of the video in a p element with id="demo"
  var shown = document.getElementById("shown"),
  hidden = document.getElementById("hidden");
  shown.innerHTML = Math.round(vid.currentTime);
  hidden.innerHTML = "Shown 2s-7s " + Math.round(vid.currentTime);

  if (vid.currentTime > 2 && vid.currentTime < 7){
    //console.log(vid.currentTime);
    hidden.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    hidden.style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>Playback position: <span id="shown"></span></p>
<p><span id="hidden"></span></p>
```